# hibernate3 maven plugin:make hbm2java generate hibernate annotations instead of ejb3 annotations

Tags: java, hibernate, maven-2, jpa, ejb

Is there a way of forcing the hbm2java goal of [hibernate3](http://mojo.codehaus.org/maven-hibernate3/hibernate3-maven-plugin/) maven plugin to generate java classes with hibernate annotations instead of ejb3 annotations? I really do not need ejb/jpa, and hibernate annotations would suit me better because of the better integration with grails.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To my knowledge, no, `ejb3=true` in [`hbm2java`](https://www.hibernate.org/hib_docs/tools/reference/en/html_single/#d0e1193) means using EJB3/Hibernate Annotations. Quoting the [generating annotated pojos](https://forum.hibernate.org/viewtopic.php?t=994243) thread in Hibernate's forums:

> ejb3 means use JPA and Hibernate annotations; we try and generate everything we can with JPA but some things require hibernate annotations.

Maybe have a look at the Jira issue but in the current state, you can't.

Comment: Thanks!  I was getting annotations and didn't know why.  Turns out I had set ejb3=true.